# Windows proc switch

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Coming from a IDE/Language that does not have the `switch` statement I'm now seeing the switch statement in all examples that deal with windows messaging so I'm wondering what the benefit of using the `switch` is as opposed to just using an `if` statement given only one message is being handled at any one point in time?

Comment: Easier to read (convention); may/might be implemented as a jump table.

Comment: A C++ compiler can optimize a switch-statement by auto-generating a jump table.  That is however very unlikely to pay off for a window procedure, the kind of messages you are going to write *case* labels for are not likely to be clustered and there is already a great deal of overhead in message processing.  So there's only one real benefit left, everybody that reads your code will understand what you are doing.